# What part of speech is "know" in "let us know"?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, predicate

What part of speech is "know" in:

> Let us know.

"You" is the implied subject, "let" is the verb, and "us" is the indirect object.

But I'm confused about "**know**" - what is its grammatical function in this sentence?

Comment: [Edit] the question and let us know :-) what's confusing you about it.

Comment: The mistake is thinking that _us_ is the indirect object. It's not; _let_ is not a three-place predicate so it can't have an indirect object. _Us_ is the subject of the infinitive clause that _know_ is the verb of, and that clause is the direct object of _let_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, **this** sense/use of _let_ isn’t a three-place predicate. Other senses/uses can be, such as “He let me the flat at a very favourable price”, where _me_ is an actual indirect object.

Answer (score 6):

**us + know** is the **infinitive complex object** of the sentence.

Infinitive complex object explained, with examples on [English Grammar](http://englishstandarts.blogspot.com/2013/01/infinitive-complex-object.html)

> The combination of a noun in the common case or a pronoun in the
>   objective case and an infinitive used after the predicate forms a
>   **complex object**. The relation between the noun (pronoun) and the
>   infinitive is that of subject and predicate.
>
> *Key examples:*
>
> - I saw the boy raise his hand.
> - I heard him call my name.
> - I want you to know that it doesn't matter.

If you doubt about the object, just think what questions the sentence answers.

The questions are

- Let us what? *(if someone did not hear well)*
- Let us know what? *(if someone is not sure what info to give)*

Other forms of the same questions may be:

- Will you let us know?
- Would you let us know?

'Know' is a verb in *the bare infinitive form* used after a *pseudo-modal verb* 'let'.

The rule is that verbs following *modal verbs* and some verbs *(let, make, see, hear, feel, work, help)* are used without 'to' particle, in bare infinitive form.

Let us know = [You] let us [to] know.

See other examples on 'let' on [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/let-let-s)

> Let them walk home on their own. (third person)
>
> Let there be no doubt about it. (impersonal)
>
> Let’s not argue about money. We can share the costs.
>
> Don’t let’s throw away the good books with the damaged ones. We can
>   sell them.

Comment: Not quite. The infinitive clause _(for) us (to) know_ is the actual object of _let_, a verb that allows B-Raising (whence _let there be..._), and which also requires infinitives to delete both _for_ (the subject infinitive complementizer, usually deleted, even when a subject NP is present, as here), **and** _to_ (the verbal infinitive complementizer, deletable only by special dispensation, as here).